# can a quadratic equation have non real coefficent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

can quadractic equation have non real coefficent and real roots simultaneously

and  what are the conditions for  the formula of  finding the roots of quadratic

is there any formula for biquadratic  for  finding roots

Comment: $ix^2 - i = 0$.   Has real root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quadratic equation can have only up to two roots $x_i$, we can write the equation as
$$
0 = (x - x_1)(x - x_2) = x^2 - (x_1 + x_2) x + x_1 x_2 = x^2 + b x + c
$$
Here the coefficients $1, b, c$ are real as well, if the $x_i$ were real.

You can come up with different equations with the same roots by multiplying both sides with a factor $f$. If that $f$ is complex with imaginary part (and $b$ and $c$ non-zero), you
end up with non-real coefficients $f, fb, fc$ and keep the real roots.

Answer (score 0):

The (real) number $1$ is a root of the quadratic equation $ix^2=i$.

Comment: Language nitpick: $1$ is the *solution to* $ix^2 = i$, and a *root of* the polynomial $ix^2 - i$.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, you are right.